# Linux user-space ELF loader

Tags: linux, arm, loader, elf, manual

I need to do a rather unusual thing: manually execute an elf executable. I.e. load all sections into right places, query main() and call it (and cleanup then). Executable will be statically linked, so there will be no need to link libraries. I also control base address, so no worries about possible conflicts.

So, is there are any libraries for that?

I found OSKit and its liboskit_exec, but project seems to be dead since 2002.

I'm OK with taking parts of projects (respecting licenses, of course) and tailoring them to my need, but as I'm quite a noob in the linux world, I dont even know where to find those parts! :)

PS. I need that for ARM platform.

**UPD** Well, the matter of loading elfs seems to require some good knowledge about it (sigh), so I'm out to read some specs and manuals. And I think I will stick to bionic/linker and libelfsh. Thanks guys!

Summarized findings:

- **libelf**:  http://directory.fsf.org/project/libelf/
- **elfsh and libelfsh** (are now part of eresi): http://www.eresi-project.org/
- **elfio** (another elf library): http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfio/
- **OSKit and liboskit_exec** (outdated): http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/
- **bionic/linker**: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic

Comment: *bump* I have this exact same problem (also on ARM), however I also need to do relocation.

Comment: What happened to this?
Do you have a followup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick `apt-cache search` suggests `libelf1`, `libelfg0` and/or `libelfsh0`.  I think the `elfsh` program (in the namesake package) might be an interesting practical example of how to use `libelfsh0`.

I haven't tried any myself, but I hope they might be helpful.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

Google's Android, in it's "bionic" libc implementation, has a completely reimplemented ELF loader.  It's reasonably clean, and probably a better source than gilbc if you're looking for something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libelf](http://directory.fsf.org/project/libelf/) for reading the executable format. You are going to have trouble with this I think.

Sounds like, as you don't need libraries for anything, why not just mmap your executable, set data about various memory areas and jmp/b in?

I don't know if ARM has an NX-bit equivalent, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

This tool contains an ELF loader: http://bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html

I reused the code from rtldi for an ELF chainloader in another project.  The code is here: `http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/plash/trunk/chroot-jail/elf-chainloader/?rev=877` and there is some background here: `http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/Story16`.  (Apparently I have to break these links because stackoverflow won't let me post >1 link!)